# Styling a segments chart

Tags: r

I am essentially replicating [this code from UPenn](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~joseff/rstudy/week4.html) and want to add some styling to the segments, specifically I want to have different colors for whether the slope of the line is positive is negative. Other styling suggestions are welcome.

Thank you, code replicated below:

```
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- a - rnorm(10)
plot(rep(1,10),a, xlim = c(1,2), ylim = range(a,b) ,xlab = "Back and Forth",ylab = "The values",axes = F)
points(rep(2,10),b)
axis(2)
axis(1,labels = c("Back","Forth"),at = 1:2)
arrows(rep(1,10),a,rep(2,10),b,code = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the line, set the `col=` property.

```
arrows(rep(1,10),a,rep(2,10),b,code = 1, col=ifelse(a>b,"blue","orange"))
```